# Грамотно ли сформулировано: "Стоимость проезда СОСТАВИТ ..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"С 1 октября стоимость проезда СОСТАВИТ 10 рублей".

Comment: А в чем проблема? Нормальное официальное предложение. Можно написать "цена проезда".

Comment: Мне не нравятся в транспорте другие фразы (из уст пассажиров). Например: "Я доеду до Парка Горького?".  

Так и хочется ответить "Да, если раньше не сойдете". Хотя, конечно, понятно, что человек хочет сказать. )))

Comment: Потому, что видит в водителе хозяина, который может его ссадить раньше.  
Смешнее бывает, когда на утвердительный ответ следующий входящий пассажир спрашивает "А я?" (Украдено Задорновым).

Comment: To DocentI: Странно! Я всегда любил и люблю так формулировать... Неужели это безвкусно?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение сформулировано грамотно. Наверное, в другой части объявления говорится, что это произойдет 1 октября 2012 года и что эта стоимость относится к автобусам, то есть "С 1 октября 2012 года стоимость проезда в городских автобусах составит 10 руб."

Answer (score 0):

Стоимость проезда - это нормально. В повседневной речи "стоимость" это и есть цена. Более того, "цена" в каком-то смысле даже хуже, хотя и правильнее. Дело в том, что цена у простых смертных пассажиров (а крутые финансисты в автобусах обычно не ездят) вызывает некоторые ложные нежелательные ассоцииации. То ли финансовой политики (закупочные цены, потребительские цены), то ли рынка ("Дама, в какую цену ваши семечки?").

Насчет "составит". Это тоже нормально.
4. Явиться чем-л., представить собой что-л. С. чьё-л. счастье. Не составит большого труда что-л. сделать. Это не составит исключения.
(БТС Кузнецова)

Comment: Вообще-то автор вопроса выделяет слово "составит".  

А предложение мне нравится. Особенно его числовая часть: нам бы такие цены! ;-))

Comment: Ой, действительно... Я-то на подобные "выделения" стараюсь внимания не обращать.
Но тут-то о чем спорить?

Comment: Да, непонятно. Хотя разные случаи бывают. Как-то корректору у нас в офсетке не понравилось мое выражение "точка отстоит от перпендикуляра на...". Она считала, что отстоять можно Родину в бою. Пришлось смотреть в справочник, я оказалась права, такой смысл тоже есть.  

Думаю, у нас были просто разные языковые области. Все-таки пример был специализорованный, математический.

Answer (score 0):

Честнее сказать, что с 1 октября стоимость проезда будет повышена до 10 рублей (или понижена, что ещё честнее). (:

Answer (score 0):

с 1 октября стоимость проезда повышается до 10 рублей.